# How can I get current value of point on candlestick?

Tags: anychart

```
anychart.data.loadCsvFile('testData3.csv',function (data){ 
    var dataTable = anychart.data.table();
    dataTable.addData(data);
    mapping = dataTable.mapAs({'open': 1, 'high': 2, 'low': 3, 'close': 4});
    chart = anychart.stock();
    var candlestick = chart.plot(0).candlestick(mapping);
    chart.container("container");
    chart.draw();
    });
});
```

How can I get current value ("open", "close") of any point onClick or mouseMove?

Answer (score 0):

The stock chart doesn't support point related events due to data optimizations. But if you really need this interactivity, it can be done with some extra JS code. For details, check [the sample](https://playground.anychart.com/VlH7YThU/0).